# How to determine scopes for an access token

Tags: google-oauth

The title says it all. Is there an API call in the Google APIs which, when given an access_token or a refresh_token, returns the scopes that are granted to that token. I could not find anything about this question in Google's documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is !

Just call this URL :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=XXXXX
```

The result looks like this. You'll only get the email if you included an email-related scope in your token.

```
{
 "issued_to": "407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "audience": "407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "user_id": "1170123456778279183758",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
 "expires_in": 3585,
 "email": "someone@yourdomain.com",
 "verified_email": true,
 "access_type": "offline"
}
```

[More info on this blog post](http://david-codes.blogspot.com/2014/07/google-apis-checking-scopes-contained.html).